# Android how to remove gridlayout from the project?

Tags: android, eclipse, project, grid-layout

I added grid layout to my project at the start and eclipse added a bunch of stuff. Now, though I am not using this layout. I want to remove it.

I can see the following from my properties file:

```
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=../gridlayout_v7
```

When I remove the line

```
android.library.reference.1=../gridlayout_v7
```

I get compile errors relating to my R.java class.

I cannot seem to find a proper way to remove this package. Anybody knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that there is also an android.support.v7.gridlayout generated in the gen package. I tried deleting it but eclipse adds it back.

Comment: On further note when I remove the grid layout from .properties file R.java also gets removed.

Comment: Things can change a lot in 2 mins. Turns out deleting the grid-layout line from .properties file is the way to go. The R.java got generated when I fixed 1 layout issue I had in my string.xml file.

Comment: Don't change anything in /gen folder, especially the R.java. It is automatically generated by Android.

Answer (score 3):

@Nightshadow please right click on project and select properties and then select android now you will able to see Library pane in below area from there you can remove grideview layout library